# Setting up kubernetes dashboard for typhoon

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard, typhoon-kubernetes

We are using https://github.com/poseidon/typhoon for our kubernetes cluster setup.
I want to set up a dashboard for kubernetes similar to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html and I am able to get the dashboard on my localhost

The issue with this is that "EVERY USER HAS TO FOLLOW THE SAME TO ACCESS THE DASHBOARD"

I was wondering if there was some way wherein we can access the dashboard via DomainName and everyone should be able to access it without much pre-set up required.

Answer (score 1):

In [dashboard documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/README.md) you can read:

> Using Skip option will make Dashboard use privileges of Service
>   Account used by Dashboard. Skip button is disabled by default since
>   1.10.1. Use --enable-skip-login dashboard flag to display it.

So you can add `--enable-skip-login` to the dashboard to display skip button.
If your users don't want to login, they can click Skip button during login and use privileges of Dashboard service account.